# differential equation $ax^\alpha y''+bx^{\alpha-1}y'+y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the differential equation $$ax^\alpha y''+bx^{\alpha-1}y'+y=0$$ where $a,b,n,\alpha$ are constants to be found to have one of the solution $y_1=\cos(x^n)$, and then solve the equation.

I tried to use the substitution of $y=\cos{x^n}$ as suggested and I got something like $$-\cos(x^n)n^2 x^{2n-2}-\sin(x^n)n(n-1)x^{n-2}-\frac{b}{a}\sin(x^n)nx^{n-2}+\frac{1}{a}x^{-\alpha}\cos(x^n)=0$$

Which cannot take me anywhere near a neat solution, any hint is appreciated!

Comment: Yes, that's the second part of the question. But I need to know the conditions of those constant to make $y=\cos(x^n)$ hold, and the equation I derived looks messy.

Comment: Factorising, you find $$\cos(x^n)(1-an^2x^{2n-2+\alpha})-nx^{n-2+\alpha}\sin(x^n)(a(n-1)+b)=0$$ and by inspection, choosing $n=1$, $b=0$, $\alpha=0$ and $a=1$ makes $\cos(x^n)$ a solution to your problem. Are there any constraints on the values of your constants?

Comment: @Mattos Are $y_1$ and $y'$ the same ?

Comment: @Qwerty I'm not sure what you mean. The OP is trying determine the values of $n$, $a$, $b$ and $\alpha$ s.t $y_{1} = \cos(x^{n})$ is a solution to his ODE. Using $y_{1}$, he/she is then going to use reduction of order to find the second solution.